# Data management outputted from a transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a smart contract in which I simulate an event through a set that manually inputs certain data like this: (I use Remix)

```
[ "From", "to", "object", [ "rules1", "rules2"]], [[1, "data1"], [2, "data2"], [3, "data3"]]
```

This is my code:

```
pragma experimental "v0.5.0";
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract StructContract {

    struct Certificate{
        uint id;
        string data;
    }
    
    struct StructEvent {
        string _from;
        string _to;
        string _object;
        string[] _rules;
    }
    
    StructEvent structEvent;
    Certificate[] certificate;
    
    function setEvent(StructEvent eventS,Certificate[] eventC)  public{
            certificate.length=0;
            structEvent = eventS;
            for(uint i=0;i<(eventC.length);i++){
              certificate.push(Certificate(eventC[i].id,eventC[i].data));
            }
    }
    function getStruct() view public returns(StructEvent){
        return(structEvent);
    }
    function getCertificate() view public returns(Certificate[]){
        return(certificate);
    }
    function returnAllData() view public returns(StructEvent,Certificate[]){
        return(structEvent,certificate);
    }
    
}
```

once this is done, what I expect is that these data are put into a transaction that is then uploaded to blockchain. Then I have to take the data in these transactions to perform checks on them.

So I need to have data that are put on blockchain, as a solution to this problem I created this code: (I use web3 1.0.0-beta.36)

```
function printTransaction(txHash) {
  
  web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash, function (error, tx) {
    if (tx != null) {
      var inputData = tx.input;
      try {
        var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, tx.to);
        var result = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(['tuple(string,string,string,string[])',
          'tuple(uint,string)[]'], inputData.slice(10));
        var data1 = result[0];
        var data2 = result[1];
        console.log("\n\n");
        console.log("--- transactions ---");
        console.log("   tx hash         : " + tx.hash + "\n"
          + "   nonce           : " + tx.nonce + "\n"
          + "   blockHash       : " + tx.blockHash + "\n"
          + "   blockNumber     : " + tx.blockNumber + "\n"
          + "   transactionIndex: " + tx.transactionIndex + "\n"
          + "   from            : " + tx.from + "\n"
          + "   to              : " + tx.to + "\n"
          + "   value           : " + tx.value + "\n"
          + "   gasPrice        : " + tx.gasPrice + "\n"
          + "   gas             : " + tx.gas + "\n"
          + "   input           : " + tx.input + "\n"
          + "   decodeinput     : " + "\n"
          + "                     Struct          : " + data1 + "\n"
          + "                     Certificates    : " + data2);

        web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, account) {
          myContract.methods.setEvent(data1, data2).send({ from: account[0], gas: 3000000 }, function (err, resul) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("err");
            } else {
              console.log("\n\n");
              console.log("--- data ---");
              myContract.methods.returnAllData().call().then(console.log);
            }
          });
        });
      } catch (Error) { }
    }
  });
}
```

What I decided to do is create, in a js file, a method that was able to take the transactions, decode the input related to the data contained in it and pass this data, through the send, to my smart contract in which it will be used.

These methods that I created represent the right solution? or I have to use another kind of approach, another method to do this?